# Blade components with variables and vite

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-blade, vite

I've built a simple blade component that gets reused in various places on a page but with different size classes applied using the Tailwind utility classes. I'm passing the size into the component and building the classes using it.

```
@props(['size' => 10])
<img class="mx-auto h-{{ $size }} w-{{ $size }} rounded-full" src="https://place-hold.it/256">
```

It appears that the bundling process doesn't recognize or know how to deal with that. I can throw all of the classes I need for it into a commented out line and it renders just fine but that defeats the whole purpose of being able to pass in arbitrary values for the properties in the first place. Is there a best practice for making this work?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It turns out to be a Tailwind config. It's probably not the best way around it but I added this stanza to my tailwind.config.js which forces it to include all height and width classes in the build.

```js
    safelist: [
        {
            pattern: /(h|w)-/,
        },
    ],
```